# Crafty element with 2 gravity's

Tags: javascript, craftyjs

I'm trying to understand Crafty. Here's my code.

```
Crafty.init(500,300, document.getElementById('game'));

Crafty.e('Floor, 2D, Canvas, Color')
  .attr({x: 0, y: 250, w: 200, h: 10})
  .color('green');

Crafty.e('SecondFloor, 2D, Canvas, Color')
  .attr({x: 250, y: 230, w: 200, h: 10})
  .color('red')

Crafty.background('#FFFFFF url(http://samenvattingleren.nl/img/img2.jpg) no-repeat center center');

Crafty.e('2D, Canvas, Color, Fourway, Gravity')
  .attr({x: 25, y: 5, w: 50, h: 50})
  .color('orange')
  .fourway(4)
  .gravity("Floor")
  .bind('KeyDown', function(e) {
    if(e.key == Crafty.keys.LEFT_ARROW) {
    this.x = this.x - 1;
    } else if (e.key == Crafty.keys.RIGHT_ARROW) {
        this.x = this.x + 1;
    } else if (e.key == Crafty.keys.UP_ARROW) {
    this.y = this.y - 1;
    } else if (e.key == Crafty.keys.DOWN_ARROW) {
    this.y = this.y + 1;
    } else if (e.key == Crafty.keys.ESC) {
        this.x = 0;
    }
  })
```

I want to add

```
Crafty.e('2D, Canvas, Color, Fourway, Gravity')
      .attr({x: 25, y: 5, w: 50, h: 50})
      .color('orange')
      .fourway(4)
      .gravity("Floor")
      .gravity("SecondFloor") //This is what i want to add
```

But this doesnt work. The square still goes trough SecondFloor

Answer (score 1):

The "Floor" component should be thought of as a kind of tag, which you'll add to any entity that should act as a floor.  In your example code, there doesn't seem to be any need to distinguish between "Floor" and "SecondFloor", so you could just change the latter to "Floor".

If you have two [custom components](http://craftyjs.com/documentation/components.html) which you want to always act as a floor, the solution is to have them require the "Floor" component automatically.  For instance

```
Crafty.c("IcePlatform", {
    init: function(){ this.requires("Floor"); }
    // Stuff specific to "IcePlatform"
};

Crafty.c("MovingPlatform", {
    init: function(){ this.requires("Floor"); }
    // Stuff specific to "MovingPlatform"
};
```

Then whenever any entity which has "MovingPlatform" or "IcePlatform" will also act as a "Floor", and interact appropriately with Gravity.